# how to use this function in linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Given we cannot use a function in this scenario, what could be good way of incorporation GetPreferredName function within Linq query?

```
List<Employee> Employees = (from d in context.Employees
                            join a in context.Address on d.ID equals a.EmployeeID
                            select new Employee
                            {
                                Id = d.Id,
                                PreferredName = GetPreferredName(d.FirstName, d.MiddleName, d.LastName, d.Alias),
                                StreetAddress = a.StreetAddress 
                            }).ToList();

private string GetPreferredName(string firstName, string middleName, string lastName, string dnsName)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName))
            return firstName;
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(middleName))
                return middleName;
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName))
                return lastName;
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dnsName))
                return dnsName;

            return "";
        }
```

Comment: making static doesn't solve thee problem

Comment: @PrestonGuillot why would making it `static` make any difference? The problem is due to the fact that the method can't be translated to SQL.

Comment: What kind of ORM are you using - LinqToSql or EntityFramework *(what version)*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is enumerate from the database first, then do a new select to run your extra code:

```
var Employees = 
    (from d in context.Employees
    join a in context.Address on d.ID equals a.EmployeeID
    select new //select the important bits we'll need in memory
    {
        Employee = d,
        Address = a,
    })
    .AsEnumerable() //AsEnumerable() it to make it enumerate from the database, now everything you need is in memory
    .Select(x => new Employee
    {
        Id = x.Employee.Id,
        PreferredName = GetPreferredName(x.Employee.FirstName, x.Employee.MiddleName, x.Employee.LastName, x.Employee.Alias),
        StreetAddress = x.Address.StreetAddress 
    })
    .ToList();
```

Also, with linq, you don't need to do these joins manually, you could change it to this:

```
var Employees = context.Employees.Select(e => 
    select new //select the important bits we'll need in memory
    {
        Employee = e,
        Address = e.Address, //join is done for you!
    })
    .AsEnumerable() //AsEnumerable() it to make it enumerate from the database, now everything you need is in memory
    .Select(x => new Employee
    {
        Id = x.Employee.Id,
        PreferredName = GetPreferredName(x.Employee.FirstName, x.Employee.MiddleName, x.Employee.LastName, x.Employee.Alias),
        StreetAddress = x.Address.StreetAddress 
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: You should use `AsEnumerable` to indicate that subsequent operations should be performed using Linq to Objects instead of using the query provider.  This accomplishes the same goal while maintaining deferred execution, allows streaming of the data, and doesn't waste time populating a list that is never used.

Comment: thanks for the heads up. I never really knew what the purpose of `AsEnumerable` was, I've updated my answer.

Comment: You should be fetching out the individual columns of the `Employee` that is used, not the whole object, otherwise you end up projecting a lot of data, sending it across the network, and populating entities on the client side, all needlessly.

Comment: This is true, but who knows what he actually needs it for. I, for one, would make a partial class for `Employee` that has a Property for `PreferredName` instead of doing this explicit select everywhere.

Comment: if have a where clause on database query, where will it go in this solution?

Comment: @pauldeter Anywhere before `AsEnumerable`.

Comment: If you want to put a where clause, you should put it before the `AsEnumerable` to have it go to SQL, or after it to have it run in memory. Depends on what you're `Where`ing on.

Comment: @DLeh Then why did you not use that as your answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ?? [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).

```
PreferredName = d.FirstName ?? d.MiddleName ?? d.LastName ?? d.Alias
```

Or ?: [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

```
PreferredName = (d.FirstName != null && d.FirstName != "") ? d.FirstName :
   ((d.MiddleName != null && d.MiddleName != "") ? d.MiddleName : 
   ((d.LastName != null && d.LastName != "") ? d.LastName : d.Alias))
```

Comment: It works, but it's rather difficult to read. (And I personally think that making a ternary operator for inline if-else if conditionals is a code smell.) :)

Comment: @Cameron It is ugly, but **it is a lot better than retrieving all columns and manipulating at Sever Memory** *(see Servy's comment in other answer)*. The problem is **ORM** cannot generates C# function into SQL; you can only use basic string manipulation. You [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27807393/296861) will throw exception at run time, because ORM doesn't know **GetPreferredName** function is.

Comment: @Win DLeh's code only pulls down every column because he was lazy and didn't specify the columns needed.  Had he done so the code would function just fine.  Also I wouldn't expect the query provider to support the null coalescing operator.  I'm not positive, but I'd be surprised to see it supported.